# Convert jQuery scrollTop to Javascript to invert scroll direction

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I'm trying to convert some jQuery code to Vanilla JS. The purpose is to invert the scroll direction of a container. The jQuery version works fine. However I'm struggling to convert it in JS.

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    $(".container").css('bottom',$(window).scrollTop()*-1);
});
```

The JS:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

var scroll =  window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    container.style.bottom = "";
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are you struggling with? The JS you posted just grabs the current vertical scroll position and on scroll unsets the bottom style of a `.container` element. In case you don't know _how_ to implement it:
1) Make a function that returns the current scroll position
2) On each scroll event call the function
3) Assign the returned value/scroll position with a negative multiplication (* -1) to the `.style.bottom` property on the container, don't forget to tack "px" onto the value (`.style.bottom = VALUE + "px";`)

Comment: @David Thank you. What I don't sucess to do is to convert `$(window).scrollTop()*-1)`as a value for `container.style.bottom`. That's for why I left the value empty in the JS code above.

Comment: You're trying to achieve X by thinking Y is the solution without providing a [mcve] and more context and expectations - therefore  this question seems to be an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider working with CSS `position:fixed` and without JS. Otherwise, as I said in the first comment:

1.) Make a function that returns the current scroll position

```
function getScrollPosition() {
  return Math.max(
    window.scrollY, // same as window.pageYOffset
    document.documentElement.scrollTop,
    document.body.scrollTop
  );
}
```

2.) On each scroll event call the function

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  const scrollY = getScrollPosition();
  // ... rest elided ...
});
```

3.) Assign the returned value/scroll position with a negative multiplication (* -1) to the `.style.bottom` property on the container, don't forget to tack "px" onto the value

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  const scrollY = getScrollPosition();
  container.style.bottom = -1 * scrollY + 'px'; // doesn't matter if " or ' is used
});
```

---

Try it:

> Hint: Use the devtools to see the inline styles being updated on the container element

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

function getScrollPosition() {
  return Math.max(
    window.scrollY, // same as window.pageYOffset
    document.documentElement.scrollTop,
    document.body.scrollTop
  );
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  const scrollY = getScrollPosition();
  container.style.bottom = -1 * scrollY + 'px'; // doesn't matter if " or ' is used
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 110vh;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  I move
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. Your solution works great. I made an example with the final result. You were right I should have made it before: [link](https://codepen.io/mathieupreaud/pen/rNPzbmz)